# How to wirte href attribute on if else condition on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-blade

I need to check 'perPage=100' and 'perPage=50' over URL on if-else clause.

```
 @if(perPage=100)
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm ajax-link back-btn" href="invoice-list?perPage=100" type="button" >Back to List</a>
@elseif(perPage=50)
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm ajax-link back-btn" href="invoice-list?perPage=50" type="button" >Back to List</a>
@else
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm ajax-link back-btn" href="invoice-list?perPage=10" type="button" >Back to List</a>
@endif
```

Comment: You should add more information to your question

Comment: First, here `perPage`  should be `$perPage` .You can use the ternary operator to avoid the if else condition.



    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm ajax-link back-btn" href="invoice-list?perPage={{(isset($perPage)&&!empty($perPage))?$perPage:10}}" type="button" >Back to List</a>

Answer (score 0):

you can only write this line without any if:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-sm ajax-link back-btn" href="{{url('invoice-list?perPage=' . $perPage)}}" type="button">Back to List</a>
```

make sure that you have $perPage variable

Comment: How do I get $perPage variable? 
I get this route 
http://server:8088/bangla-tissue-latest-version-update/bPack#invoiceChalan?sales_invoice_master_id=24
from Softarware when go into 'Back to list' Page.